# Something wrong when I compile and install vim7.4

Tags: linux, vim

when I compile and install vim 7.4,I have some error. Steps are as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/.opt/vim74 --with-features=huge --enable-netbeans --enable-multibyte
make
make install
```

when I excute command 'make'，I got the following error information.

> make[1]: execvp: echo: Permission denied
>
> make[1]: [auto/pathdef.c] Error 127 (ignored)
>
> ......
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/src/vim74/src/po'
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/src/vim74/src/po'
>
> make[2]: Nothing to be done for `converted'.
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/src/vim74/src/po'
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/src/vim74/src'

And the command 'make install' gave me the following errors.

> ......
>
> installing /home/user/.opt/vim74/share/man/man1/vim.1
>
> installing /home/user/.opt/vim74/share/man/man1/vimtutor.1
>
> installing /home/user/.opt/vim74/share/man/man1/vimdiff.1
>
> installing /home/user/.opt/vim74/share/man/man1/evim.1
>
> make[1]: execvp: echo: Permission denied
>
> make[1]: *** [installrtbase] Error 127
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/src/vim74/src'
>
> make: *** [install] Error 2

I have no root permission and I am also not a sudoer
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on /home/user/.opt/vim74?

Comment: Hint: have a single `--prefix=/home/user/pub` for all your applications that you compile; then add `/home/user/pub/bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: I try to set the permission 777,but it also did not work.

Comment: and I am not in sudo list

Answer (score 0):

is it ubuntu? If it is, just install

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

```
./configure \
    --enable-perlinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic \
    --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-cscope \
    --enable-gui=auto \
    --enable-gtk2-check \
    --enable-gnome-check \
    --with-features=huge \
    --with-x \
    --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.6/config
```

then

```
make && sudo make install
```

that should enable x11 and clipboard support, verified under ubuntu10.04.

Answer (score -1):

when you use `make install`, try `sudo make install` instead.

Sorry, I do not know you are not in `sudo` list. Can you give more error context information?

Comment: He does not have root privileges and he is not on the sudoers list

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

ensure you have enough permission

Comment: sorry,I am not in sudo list